Animated series begin 2000s or just before with samurai and evil twin
I dont remember much just that you had a guy with a sword (samurai maybe) and his two friends, a guy and a girl, (could also be 2 guys) but one of them had earth powers and something like a lionshead? And the other had water powers. There mission was to bring another girl somewhere or protect her. And the samurai guy had an evil shadow twin. I dont think it was his actual twin, more like a evil manifestation of his bad side. Hopefully someone knows what this is. Good luck xd

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you watch this?  What language was it in?  (Had it been dubbed or subtitled?)

Is this Shinzo (2000), originally titled Mushrambo in Japan...?

In the world of Mushrambo, human life has all but come to an end. After a deadly virus threatened the extinction of mankind, a new race called the Enterrans was created to preserve life on Earth. However, relations between the Enterrans and their creators did not remain peaceful. Soon a war broke out with the Enterrans fighting against the humans and their robots. Ultimately the Enterrans were the victors of this conflict, renaming Earth as Enterra in honor of their victory.
Before the last vestiges of humanity fell, one of the few remaining scientists put his daughter, Yakumo Shindou, into a sleep chamber. His hope was that his daughter would one day reawaken and find the human sanctuary known as Shinzo, reviving humanity and restoring peace between humans and Enterrans. Centuries have passed since the war; Yakumo now awakens and meets an Enterran named Mashura who pledges to assist in her quest. Also joined by the Enterrans Sago and Kutal, the group must now work to locate Yakumo's missing memories and locate Shinzo. But not every Enterran is as kind as Yakumo's new friends and some are prepared to commit any atrocity to prevent the return of humanity.

As noted in the summary above, the series is about a human girl named Yakumo who wakes up from suspended animation on a future Earth ruled by animal/human hybrids called Enterrans.



Yakumo is on a journey to find a sanctuary called Shinzo and befriends Mushra, Sago and Kutal, three Hyper-Enterrans who travel with her, protecting her from hostile Enterrans.



Mushra, Sago and Kutal can each transform into more powerful hyper forms. Mushra is a fire elemental who looks like a boy in his default form, and a man in red armour in his hyper form. Sago is a water elemental who looks like a man in both his default and hyper forms, but in different attire. Kutal is an earth elemental who looks like a fat, anthropomorphic cat in his default form, and an anthropomorphic lion in his hyper form.



All three can also combine to become the even more powerful Mushrambo, who wields a sword and is referred to as "The Ultimate Samurai" in the title of episode 10.



In episode 13, one of the antagonists on the show, Lord Ryuma, uses a black Encard to turn Mushrambo into Dark Mushrambo, a dark, evil version of himself.






